# Not having any luck with preg_match

Tags: php

im trying to parse a url for the last 2 / sections.
i need to get the address (can get that) and the number(second section {ie:08078612,08248595} unless its at last and no address is present {last url list example} {ie: 8274180})
i optionally need to get the last 3 digits of the second only numbers section.{ie 612,595,180}

Im not having any luck heres my code so far.

```
$url_list[] = $url;

if(preg_match("/[0-9]/",substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 1))) {
    $url_list_mls[]= substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 2);
    $url_list_mls_last3[] = substr(strrchr($url, '/'), -3); 
} else {
    $url_list_mls[]= substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 1);
    $url_list_mls_last3[] = substr(strrchr($url, '/'), -3);
}

$url_list_addy[]= substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 1);
```

Example URLs (part of the full url endings as examples)

```
/a019/08078612/214-N-CREST-Avenue
/a019/08248595/111-N-Elroy-Avenue
/a019/8274180
```

im trying to make 3 lists, address (last section) number (second section) and last 3 numbers of the second section number.

Comment: Are you sure `preg_match()` is a luck thing?

Comment: what you want to extract from these examples exactly?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're trying to do. Are these *complete* URLs? Or just parts as you've shown above? Also, what *exactly* are you trying to extract from these URLs?

Comment: @YotamOmer I think it is. I tried matching four-leafed clovers and bunny feat with it... and I wasn't lucky either...

Comment: `parse_url` or `explode`

Comment: @u_mulder substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 2); separates the value all ready and not the part im having problem with. altho explode may work as well, i don't have a problem with re-writing it if it needs to be) im having current problem if the last section is an address or a number and its not then use second section, as i need the last 3 numbers in the second sections number.

Comment: @Amal Murali i updated the post to try to explain it a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code is way complicated. You can capture all of your strings with `preg_match_all` in a single line. Since the street address part seems to be conditional, I've made it so in my pattern. Also by grouping the last 3 `{3}` in their own parenthesis we can use them as well. I wasn't sure if the `a019` changed, so I've included it as well, just to show how it could be done.

```
<?php

$uris = array("/a019/08078612/214-N-CREST-Avenue",
"/a019/08248595/111-N-Elroy-Avenue",
"/a019/8274180",);

$pattern = "!/([a-zA-z][0-9]+)/([0-9]+([0-9]{3}))/?([A-Za-z0-9.-]+)?/?!";

$x=0;
foreach($uris as $uri){
    preg_match_all($pattern,$uri,$matches);

    $address[$x]['scode'] = $matches[1][0];
    $address[$x]['stcode'] = $matches[2][0];
    $address[$x]['last3'] = $matches[3][0];
    if(!empty($matches[4][0])){
        $address[$x]['staddr'] = $matches[4][0];
    }
    $x++;
}


print_r($address);

?>
```

**$Address Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [scode] => a019
            [stcode] => 08078612
            [last3] => 612
            [staddr] => 214-N-CREST-Avenue
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [scode] => a019
            [stcode] => 08248595
            [last3] => 595
            [staddr] => 111-N-Elroy-Avenue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [scode] => a019
            [stcode] => 8274180
            [last3] => 180
        )

)
```

Comment: Lost a post i made so im re-saying it. Thats better then i could have hoped for never thought of separating them as an array thanks again